# All java threads are running on a single core, ultimately taking too much time to execute

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, cpu-usage

This is my homework problem:
I have to do matrix multiplication. My code should create a thread to each element in the resultant matrix. i.e., if resultant matrix is mXn size then there should be m*n threads.

(http://iit.qau.edu.pk/books/OS_8th_Edition.pdf  page 179)

Yes I finished it by my own. Which is executing fine with all my test cases. Unfortunately, I end up getting 70% credit :(
This is my code and test cases.

[Matrix Multiplication.zip](http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g3d6638d80688b5629995710698ab2a457d184d9f4)

When I met my professor regarding my marks. He told me that my code taking too long to execute larger size matrix.

I argued with him that it is a expected behavior as it is obvious that large size data takes more time. However, he disagree with me.

I attached my code and test cases . My code is taking 3 hours. As per my professor it should only take 5 min to execute.

I tried to figured out for last couple of days but I couldn't find exact solution :(

outline of my code

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors
                .newFixedThreadPool(threadCount); // creating thread pool
                                                    // with fixed threads
        int mRRowLen = matrix1.length; // m result rows length
        int mRColLen = matrix2[0].length; // m result columns length
        mResult = new long[mRRowLen][mRColLen];
        for (int i = 0; i < mRRowLen; i++) { // rows from m1
            for (int j = 0; j < mRColLen; j++) { // columns from m2
                Runnable r = new MatrixMultipliactionThread(matrix1ColLen, i, j, matrix1,
                        matrix2);
                executor.execute(r);
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
            // wait untill it get shutdown 
        }
```

Run method :

```
public void run() {

        for (int k = 0; k < m1ColLength; k++) { // columns from m1
            Matrix.mResult[i][j] += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm not going to download a zip file and go threw your entire code. Post the snippets here that you think are important.

Comment: *if resultant matrix is mXn matrix then there are mXn threads*: that is not a good idea at all. Your machine has much fewer cores than that, and creating so many threads will consume a whole lot of CPU and memory, to perform a single tiny operation. Your multiplication would probably be much much faster if you did it using a single thread. If you divide the tasks in threads, then you should have as many threads as you have cores on your machine.

Comment: *"But my professor told me that for the same test cases a perfect code will take only 5 min to execute."* - I imagine he is saying this because he has written and tested a solution that takes roughly 5 minutes.

Comment: @MikeKobit I attached some important part of the code.

Comment: And presumably `threadCount` is not `1`?

Comment: @JBNizet: My problem is, CPUs are not utilizing. Mapping of threads happening only on single processor

Comment: @StephenC NO sir, test cases are same for every student Moreover even he showed me other student code execution which executed 3 min with the same test case

Comment: @CupawnTae Obviously not

Comment: You may just be breaking down the problem too small, and each thread task is completing before the next has a chance to start. Try calling the executor in the `i` loop and putting the `j` loop inside the task instead for example.

Comment: @user2553748 you'd be surprised how many times it turns out to be something that simple, even for the most seasoned programmers. Since you didn't include that code in the question, it was worth making sure.

Comment: Your tight loop of `while (!executor.isTerminated()) { }` isn't going to be helping anything...

Comment: Note that if your code is executing *36 times* as slowly as a good solution, it's unlikely that that's solely due to threading, unless the 5 minute version was executing on a monster machine (or multiple machines)

Comment: So, what is the value of threadCount? And how many cores does your machine have? You realize that this is not creating mXn threads, right? It's creating threadCount threads.

Comment: @CupawnTae i changed the code as you mentioned but I did not see any improvement in the execution time.

Comment: First, your program is probably slow because when you submitted it the `run()` method in `MatrixMultipliactionThread` class was synchronized (which is unnecessary). And second, you shouldn't submit m X n tasks because the number of cores is way less than that, try to create mRRowLen tasks, each of which should execute the inner loop for a different row `i`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I think that's not the solution for my problem. prior to the execution of the while threads are not distributed on different cores and his machine is old than mine( he even mentioned this)

Comment: @JBNizet Hope you know the Threapool concept.which only allows fixed number of threads to execute at a time. I have taken 24 as a threadcount.

mine i5 processor i guess i have 4 cores.

It is creating mXn threads but it is not distributed in different cores rather executing in single processor

Comment: I understand the threadpool concept. I also understand what *fixed* means. I repeat: you have 24 threads (which is still too much), and not mXn. You're submitting mXn *tasks*, and these *tasks* are executed by the 24 *threads* of the pool. You're confusing *tasks* and *threads*.

Comment: @alfasin : yes i removed and tried to execute it. No change in the result. and hope you know the Threadpool concept which allows only certain number of threads at a time which i taken explicitly as threadcount.

Comment: @JBNizet ohhh!! :( got it. What i want to do now? Can you please suggest me some solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I downloaded your zip and ran the program. Your problem isn't in the matrix multiplication at all. The advice in the comments is still valid about reducing the number of threads, however as it stands the multiplication happens very quickly.

The actual problem is in your `writeToAFile` method - all the single-threaded CPU utilization you are seeing is actually happening in there, after the multiplication is already complete.

The way you're appending your strings:

```
fileOutputString = fileOutputString + resultMatrix[i][j]
```

creates thousands of new `String` objects which then immediately become garbage; this is very inefficient. You should be using a `StringBuilder` instead, something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < resultMatrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < resultMatrix[i].length; j++) {
        sb.append(resultMatrix[i][j]);
        if (j != resultMatrix[i].length - 1) sb.append(",");
    }
    sb.append("\n");
}

String fileOutputString=sb.toString();
```

That code executes in a fraction of a second.